# Why does this method of assigning a value to a divergent series fail?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, divergent-series

I was trying to figure out a way to assign values to divergent sums and found this interesting identity. Here are the steps I took to get it:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1-e} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1-e} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}$$
I believe this step is illegal, since you can't always exchange infinite sums)
$$\frac{1}{1-e} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^k$$
$$\frac{1}{1-e} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \zeta(-k)$$

For $x=-e$ this process is similar, except that
$$\frac{1}{1+e} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nn^k$$
Since the eta function is defined with the starting index of 1, we have that
$$1-\frac{1}{1+e} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn^k$$
$$-\frac{e}{1+e} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \eta(-k)$$

But, if x is not either of these the sum doesn't seem to converge properly?
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{\ln(x)n}$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\ln(x)n\right)^k}{k!}$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\ln(x)^k}{k!} \zeta(-n) $$ doesn't work, and neither does
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \zeta(-\ln(x)n) $$

On the hand, it seems that
$$1-\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\ln(x)^k}{k!} \eta(-n) $$ *does* work even if x>e.

I'm curious what causes the sum to converge properly, or what causes it to fail. How would I go about proving where this sum converges properly?

Comment: Your first illegal step is when you plug in $x=e$ which is outside the radius of convergence of the geometric series.

Comment: @Merosity Yeah, your right, normally you can't plug in something outside of the radius. My goal was to extend the radius of convergence by trying to find a reasonable way to assign a value to the series without just defining the sum to be 1/(1-e). I'm mainly curious why this method sometimes works (like with negative values of x), but sometimes doesn't. Is it just a coincidence that this works at x=e? Or is something more complicated going on?

Comment: At least one reason your final few series don’t work is because there is still an n inside even though the sum only sums in k

Comment: Even if it can be made rigourous, you have already ‘declared by fiat’ that a function is equal to the algebraic formula applied outside the usual range. You just decided to do this for $\sum n^k= \zeta(-k)$  instead of $\sum x^n = 1/(1-x)$

Comment: I'd discussed the same observatione once, maybe something interesting in it for your question: http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ProblemWithBellmatrix.pdf

Comment: @GottfriedHelms That link is very interesting, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: Because those generalised series should be taken over all k, not only starting from 0. Useally the negative k are 0 in the series you learned. So if you add k=-1 it turns out fine, other negative numbers are 0.